# How to turn integer masks into COCO format json annotation file for use with Mask RCNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, image-segmentation, mask-rcnn

I have a method for defining different regions in grayscale images that labels each instance of a region with a unique ID integer that ranges from 0 to N_objects - 1.

I would like to train a Mask RCNN model on this data and do predictions to perform instance segmentation.

I have been trying to use the [imantics](https://github.com/jsbroks/imantics) package to do this (see the minimal worked example in this GitHub [question](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/250#issuecomment-455826893)), but I'm running into this error when trying to add multiple Image objects to a Dataset object: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison".

What do I need to do? If it is indeed possible to do in imantics, how can I do that? What other packages do people use for converting between masks and COCO style annotations?

Thank you!!